# Exclusice Arc and multiple many to many relationships db design issue

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

I have an existing application that has the following entities in the database

- Customer
- InvoiceGroup
- SalesGroup

A customer can be part of multiple groups. Currently this is mapped in the following way

```
Customer table
 - cid (Pk)
 - fname
 - surname
 ----
 ---
 - invgrpdid (Fk)
 - salesid (Fk)

Invoicegroup table
 - invgrpid (Pk)
 - name
 - type
 ---
 ----

Salesgroup table
 - salesid (Pk)
 - name
 - desc
 -----
 -----
```

I now have a requirement to add a new entity campaign. A Customer can be part of multiple campaigns. A campaign is deployed for a customer group which is created by
 - selecting individual customers (custom) OR
 - selecting an existing invoicegroup (invoice) OR
 - selecting an existing salesgroup (sales)

The campaign customer list should be 
 - reusable, i.e can be used for multiple campaigns
 - dynamic, i.e if created from an invoice/sales group, changes across the invoice and sales group
   should be reflected to the campaign customer list

I am having difficulty designing for the dynamic requirement. I have come up with the following design, but it has exclusive arcs that is one key refering to multiple foreign keys which is not the recommended approach. I have thought of supertype and subtype, but I am not clear on designing the many-to-many relationships.

```
campaign
 - campaignid(Pk)
 - name
 - startdate
 - status
 ------

campaignlist
 - listid(Pk)
 - listname
 - listtype - Invoice, Sales, Custom
 - typeid (Fk) - Refers to invoicegroupid or salesgroupid depending on listtype
 -----

customercampaign
  - listid (Fk)
  - customerid (Fk)
  - status
  - dateupdated
  -------------
```

What would be a better approach to design this considering referential integrity and normalization.
The most frequent query run multiple times daily will be to retrieve all campaign information for a customer. So need to be mindful of multiple tables and joins.

Comment: When you say, "I am not clear on designing the many-to-many relationships", what many-to-many relationships are you talking about?

Comment: @Catcall - I meant the many-to-many relationships for customer and campaign table and for invoicegroup and campaign and salesgroup and campaign. As Eric Smith suggested I had thought about separate joining tables for each of them, but was wondering if there was any other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first stab, I would do something like this:

```
CampaignList
    - ID (PK)
    - Name

CustomerCampaignList
    - CampaignListID (FK to CampaignList.ID)
    - CustomerID (FK)
      UNIQUE (CampaignListID, CustomerID)

SalesGroupCampaignList
    - CampaignListID (PK,FK to CampaignList.ID)
    - SalesGroupID (FK)
      UNIQUE (CampaignListID, SalesGroupID)

InvoiceGroupCampaignList
    - CampaignListID (PK,FK to CampaignList.ID)
    - InvoiceGroupID (FK)
      UNIQUE (CampaignListID, InvoiceGroupID)
```

That is, use table inheritance.  This is quite a normalised design, which in my opinion is the approach to take when you're not yet clued up on specific requirements.  Optionally, you could make your life easier by denormalising a little and putting a `CampaignListTypeID` in the `CampaignList` table.  In this case though, it would be difficult to maintain the integrity of the data model without writing logic in a trigger.

I'm assuming that you won't ever have to do interesting combination groups e.g., 2 x sales group + invoice group + a set of customers.

Comment: the interesting combination comes under the custom category, wherein you store reference to the customer instead of the group. So the customercampaignlist table would take care of that scenario. For your first approach, it could be many-to-many relationship for all 3 tables, which means I can't use the second approach as a list could comprise of 1 or more groups, but will not comprise of a combination of groups and individual customers. Is there a way to implement this using supertype /sub-types?

Comment: I was working on the definition that you provided i.e.,: "A campaign is deployed for a customer group which is created by - selecting individual customers (custom) OR - selecting an existing invoicegroup (invoice) OR - selecting an existing salesgroup (sales)".  The way I interpret this is that the three options are mutually exclusive ... you can choose to define your campaign in terms of individual customers, *or* in terms of a sales group, *or* in terms of an invoice group, but not a combination of the three.

Comment: U are right, they are mutually exclusive(well in a way atleast), however a campaign can be defined in terms of 1+ sales group or 1+  invoice groups, where the separate tables scenario would work. A campaign WILL NOT BE DEFINED as a combination of sales group and invoice group or sales group and individual customers etc. Also there is one important requirement, that I missed,  the most frequent query run multiple times a day would be to find out all campaigns that a customer belongs to. So I guess, I need to be mindful of the joins as well. I have edited the question to include the requirement.

Comment: @Angela, that's the most normalised design IMO.  It's important to be practical, I agree, but beware of premature optimisation.  Build something with that design and then test your theory about the performance implications of complex joins.

Comment: I have accepted your answer Eric, however we went with a slightly different design, but I can say it was inspired by your design of different tables for salesgroup and invoicegroup. Our salesgroupcampaign table is a mapping between campaignid and salesgroupid,instead of listid and salesgroupid. We only store a separate customercampaignlist if its a custom list made of customers from different groups. This makes it easier to retrieve campaigns for a particular customer.